# a question how to compute the eigenvalues of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a question:
Suppose I have a  $n\times n$ matrix:
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 1 &...& 1 \\
        1 & 1 &...&1 \\
        \vdots&\vdots &\ddots & \vdots&\\
        1 & 1 & ...&1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
,then is there a easy way to compute the eigenvalues of the matrix?

How can I compute this matrix eigenvalue?

Comment: Please search before asking.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Since all the columns are the same, the matrix has rank $1$. Thus, all but one of the eigenvalues are $0$. Can you guess an eigenvector which corresponds to the non-zero eigenvalue, and determine this non-zero eigenvalue?

Comment: I think it should be  n, but how to determine whether how many zero eigenvalues(the multiples of the eigenvalue 0) it has?

Comment: In general, if an $n \times n$ matrix has rank $r$, then exactly $n-r$ eigenvalues are $0$.